# Group dates by certain range in R

Tags: r, sorting, date

let's say I have a list of dates from March 1st to July 15th:

```
daterange = as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2020-3-1"), as.Date("2020-7-15"), "days"))
```

I want to group the dates by 1-15 and 16-30/31 for each month. So the dates in March will be separated into two groups: Mar 1-15 and Mar 16-31. Then keep doing this for every month.

I know the `lubridate` package can sort by week, but I don't know how to set a custom range.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a logical vector on `day` as well as a group on `yearmon`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
daterange2 <- daterange %>%
                set_names('Date') %>% 
                group_by(yearmon = as.yearmon(Date), 
                    Daygroup = (day(Date) > 15) + 1) %>%
                mutate(Label = str_c(format(Date, '%b'), 
                  str_c(min(day(Date)), max(day(Date)), sep='-'), sep= ' '))
```

Comment: Now what if I wanted to label Apr 1-15 as Daygroup 3 and Apr 16-31 as Daygroup 4 (and keep going for the next months)? Would it be easier just to subset the data by month?

Comment: @Shuwei updated the answer.  You can use the `month` also as. grouping, but I was thinking that you need to have different groups for different years?

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, you can create two groups in each month by pasting the month value from each date and assign value 1/2 based on the date.

```
newdaterange <- transform(daterange, group = paste0(format(date, "%b"), '-group-',
                          ifelse(as.integer(format(date, "%d")) > 15, 1, 2)))
```